# Meteor getting data from router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm having trouble getting data from iron:router.
Im trying to get the data by param._id and then pass it to my template.created to set a session variable for editing purposes.

Here is my code in the router:

```
Router.route('/edit/:_id', function(){
    this.render('edit', {
        data: function(){

                return Collection.findOne({_id: this.params._id})
        }
    })  
})
```

And then I want to access that data here:

```
Template.edit.created = function(){

   data = ???
   Session.set('edit', data)
   $(input).val(data.post)

}
```

If i do `console.log( this )` I get `Blaze.TemplateInstance`.

But when I `console.log(this)` in Template.edit.events I get the document I want from the iron:router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For template.created and template.rendered you can access the data with `this.data`.

Answer (score 1):

I've used `Template.currentData();` and managed to access the data in template.created but can someone explain why "this" in template.created and template.events refers to 2 different things?

Comment: Please do not ask questions in answers. It can lead to lengthy discussions in the comments. If you need to ask something else, make a new question. Don't forget also to accept your own answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input, still learning the ways of Stack, and I wanted to accept my answer but it says I can't to that for 2 days.